# WhatsApp screenshot functionality, iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, whatsapp

We all hear the rumour that **WhatsApp would notify you each time someone took a screenshot of your conversation**.

My question is, **How is it possible in iOS to achieve this functionality?**

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationuserdidtakescreenshotnotification?language=objc

Comment: See [several other search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification).

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy :)